# Adjacency Matrix Not Including Vertices

Tags: r, adjacency

I have a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame and I would like to create an adjacency matrix. However, I would like to only count two polygons as adjacent if they share more than just vertices (i.e. they share an edge, not just a point). gTouches says polygons are adjacent if they share at least one point (e.g. just one vertex).

My thought was to run:

```
AdjMat <- gTouches(map, byid=TRUE)
```

then go look at the intersections for the adjacent polygons that identifies to see if the intersection is a line or a point.

```
test <- gIntersection(map[x,],map[y,])
exists("test@lines")
```

Playing around I find "test" is "Formal class SpatialLines" if x and y share an edge, and "Formal class SpatialPoints" if they just share a vertex (and "NULL (empty)" if they aren't adjacent at all. The problem I'm having is that even when it is "Formal class SpatialLines" and "test@lines" is actually in my environment, exists("test@lines") returns FALSE. (When it is "Formal class SpatialPoints, "test@lines" is not available, but "test@coords" is, but exists("test@coords") also returns FALSE.)

How do I get an adjacency matrix that doesn't count polygons as adjacent if their shared boundary/intersection is only one-dimensional?

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example for us to play around with?

Comment: @MichaelChirico I'm using [link]http://legis.wisconsin.gov/ltsb/gisdocs/ElectionData/GIS/WISELR_Wards_WTM8391_041712.zip

if you do `map<-readOGR(dsn="WISELR_Wards_WTM8391_041712", layer="WISELR_Wards_WTM8391_041712")`

then `AdjMat<-gTouches(map, byid=TRUE)` you will for example get an adjacency matrix showing that, e.g., wards 2163 and 3220 are adjacent, but your answer below shows they only share a point in common. Your answer solves it. I just needed `class` instead of `exists`, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a double loop, but it gets the job done -- you were definitely on the right track. You could do some initial work minimization by using `gTouches` first.

Here's an example:

```
library(sp)
library(rgeos)
square = cbind(c(0, 1, 1, 0),
                c(0, 0, 1, 1))
ex = 
  SpatialPolygons(list(
    Polygons(list(Polygon(square)), 'a'),
    Polygons(list(Polygon(sweep(square, 2L, c(1, 0), '+'))), 'b'),
    Polygons(list(Polygon(sweep(square, 2L, c(1, 1), '+'))), 'c'),
    Polygons(list(Polygon(sweep(square, 2L, c(0, 1), '+'))), 'd'),
    Polygons(list(Polygon(sweep(square, 2L, c(5, 5), '+'))), 'e'),
    #gTouches returns FALSE for this polygon, even though it _overlaps_ a through d
    Polygons(list(Polygon(sweep(square, 2L, c(.5, .5), '+'))), 'f')))
```

We just loop through pairs of polygons and check if the `class` of their intersection is `SpatialLines` -- if so, they intersect by your definition, otherwise (`SpatialPolygons`, `SpatialPoints`, or `NULL`), they don't:

```
polyids = seq_along(ex)
adjMat = matrix(FALSE, ncol = length(ex), nrow = length(ex))
for (ii in polyids) {
  for (jj in setdiff(polyids, seq_len(ii))) {
    adjMat[ii, jj] = 
      class(gIntersection(ex[ii, ], ex[jj, ])) == 'SpatialLines'
  }
}
#use symmetry for the other half
adjMat[lower.tri(adjMat)] = t(adjMat)[lower.tri(adjMat)]

adjMat
#       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]
# [1,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# [2,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [3,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# [4,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [6,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```